# PhoneGap Build publishing error

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, onsen-ui

I just finished my first PhoneGap application, and now it would be time for me, to publish it on Google Play.

I created an android keystore file, using the tutorial found here : [Android Signing GITHUB](https://github.com/amirudin/build/wiki/Android-Signing)

I added it to the Adobe PhoneGap Build site, and it built my app without any errors in the log. This was a debug version of the app, tested the apk on an android phone and it worked without any problems.

However, after adding the key file, reinstalling it on the phone, it suddenly stopped working.

```
NetworkError: A Network error occured.
```

This happens. I have the same config.xml file where I didn't specify any permissions (so it asks for all of them, but I wanted to remove only after seeing the app working in release mode)

What is the problem? Why signing the app changes the way it works on Android?

My config.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
  <widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id="testapp" versionCode="1" version="1.0.0">
    <name>Test App</name>
    <description>
      This is a test application
    </description>
    <author email="support@mycompany.com" href="http://mycompany.com">
      My Company
    </author>

    <preference name="orientation" value="default"/>
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true"/>

    <icon src="icon.png"/>
    <gap:splash src="splash.png" />

    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
    <content src="index.html" />

    <access origin="*" />
    <engine name="android" spec="^4.0.2" />
    <plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="^3.8.0" />

</widget>
```

PhoneGap LOG:

```
-package:
  [apkbuilder] Current build type is different than previous build: forced apkbuilder run.
  [apkbuilder] Creating TestApp-release-unsigned.apk for release...

-post-package:

-release-prompt-for-password:

-release-nosign:
   [echo] No key.store and key.alias properties found in build.properties.
   [echo] Please sign /project/bin/TestApp-release-unsigned.apk manually
   [echo] and run zipalign from the Android SDK tools.
   [propertyfile] Creating new property file: /project/bin/build.prop
   [propertyfile] Updating property file: /project/bin/build.prop
   [propertyfile] Updating property file: /project/bin/build.prop
   [propertyfile] Updating property file: /project/bin/build.prop

-release-sign:

-post-build:

release:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 16 seconds
debug: Starting application signing
.....
jar signed.

Warning: 
No -tsa or -tsacert is provided and this jar is not timestamped. Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after the signer certificate's expiration date (2043-02-07) or after any future revocation date.

debug: Finished application signing
Verifying alignment of /project/bin/TestApp-release.apk (4)...
....
Verification succesful
```

LOGCAT:

beginning of /dev/log/system

E/Vold    (  574): Error reading configuration (No such file or directory)... continuing anyways

E/ConnectivityService( 1700): Ignoring protectedNetwork 14

E/MobileDataStateTracker( 1700): default: Ignoring feature request because could not acquire PhoneService

E/MobileDataStateTracker( 1700): default: Could not enable APN type "default"

E/LocationManagerService( 1700): no geocoder provider found

E/LocationManagerService( 1700): No FusedProvider found.

E/LocationManagerService( 1700): no geofence provider found

E/ConnectivityService( 1700): Unexpected mtu value: android.net.EthernetDataTracker@3294037c

E/VoldConnector( 1700): NDC Command {3 volume mount /storage/sdcard} took too long (1210ms)

E/VoldConnector( 1700): NDC Command {4 asec list} took too long (2000ms)

--------- beginning of /dev/log/main

Comment: Post your logcat here. Without it we could not help you.

Comment: I'm not using any android tools. I'm using the Phonegap Build cloud based service, to build the apk files. But i have a log file. I just updated the original post!

Comment: Install that APK file on your device and while ADB is enabled in the device run the app and monitor logcat in your computer. Then post all red lines (i.e. errors) you have gotten here.

Comment: i'm not using any android tools, as I was saying earlier. It just beats me, that the unsigned ("debug") version of the apk runs smoothly, and as soon as I sign it, it fails.

Comment: I just installed these platform tools, and made a logcat dump. There are a lot of errors as I see it (the ones starting with *:E) updated the original post.

Comment: I don't see any logcat outputs here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90316/discussion-between-laureant-and-abforce).